# h2 Database "mem:MyDB" not found [90013-192]

Tags: scala, jdbc, h2

I am trying to create database using [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), i did a run for it and connect to Generic H2 (Server) with the following sittings

Driver Class: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource

JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:mem:MyDB

username : sa

password : sa

and this is my code to use it

```scala
package MainPac
import io.getquill._
object DataBaseService  extends App {
  lazy val ctx = new H2JdbcContext(SnakeCase, "db")
  case class TEST(ID:Int,NAME :String)

  import ctx._
  var thisistest= quote {
    query[TEST].map( r => r.NAME)
  }
   ctx.run(thisistest)
}
```

and in config file

```
 `db {
 dataSourceClassName : "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
 dataSource.url : "jdbc:h2:mem:MyDB;IFEXISTS=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
 dataSource.user : "sa"
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

context definition

```
lazy val ctx = new H2JdbcContext(SnakeCase, "ctx")
```

application.properties

```
ctx.dataSourceClassName=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
ctx.dataSource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:yourdbname
ctx.dataSource.user=sa
```

Try ***yourdbname*** lower case.